# illegal input sequence at position : convert a file from Big5 to UTF8 using unix

Tags: unix, encoding, utf-8, decoding, apache-nifi

I tried to convert a file from Big5 to UTF8 using the iconv command. I am getting the error : `illegal input sequence at position 18876`

```
iconv -f BIG5 -t UTF8 doc_full_list.csv > doc_full_list.csv.out
```

When I used Apache Nifi '[ConvertCharacterSet](https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/master/nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-standard-bundle/nifi-standard-processors/src/main/java/org/apache/nifi/processors/standard/ConvertCharacterSet.java)' processor, it could successfully convert the same file.

It basically fixes the errors as below:

```
final CharsetDecoder decoder = inputCharset.newDecoder();
        decoder.onMalformedInput(CodingErrorAction.REPLACE);
        decoder.onUnmappableCharacter(CodingErrorAction.REPLACE);
        decoder.replaceWith("?");
```

Would it be possible to achieve the conversion from unix command line without using any tool ?

Comment: You are aware that it will replace untranslatable characters with a '?'  

You can do the same with the iconv command by using -f with a translit file

Comment: Thanks @Chaffelson. I am now using the '-c' option to suppress the warnings. I am able to avoid moving the data through nifi in the process. I will keep the group posted.

Comment: iconv -c -f BIG5 -t UTF-8 doc_full_list.csv -o doc_full_list.csv.test